# How does jQuery clone its methods so quickly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype, sizzle

I am trying to return a query like object, in my first try I try the `Object.create` method

```
var ElementArray = {
    someMethod : myMethod,
    ....
}

var addMethods = function(elements) {
    var obj = Object.create(ElementArray);
    obj[0] = elements;
    return obj;
};

var getId = function( query ) {
    return addMethods( doc.getElementById(query) );
};
```

[(jsperf)](http://jsperf.com/get-js-0-0-1/3)

I immediately found that this was slower then jQuery(sizzle), especially on firefox. The issues with firefox where probably to do with  cross-compartment wrappers [(see bug here)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=907369), but I was still quite dissatisfied.

I also tried using prototype instead

```
var ElementArray = function(){};
ElementArray.prototype.someMethod = someMethod;
....

var addMethods = function(elements) {
    var obj = new ElementArray();
    ....
};
```

Slightly better on Chome, but still very slow on firefox.

So my question is, how does jQuery(sizzle), and other libraries do it || Whats the fastest way to return a object with a 1-2 instance properties? (Everything else can just be references)

Comment: jQuery uses the `prototype` for its methods.  So, there's no work to do when creating a new object other than the system setting the prototype reference.

Comment: @jfriend00 Searching through sizzles github repo  I am not finding the the  prototype method (I searched for) `.prototype` ... Am I missing something?

Comment: Internally, it uses `.fn`, but that is aliased to `.prototype` and it's not actually on `jQuery`, but on a different object.

Comment: See the jQuery function here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L18.  It's the `jQuery.init.prototype` and see here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, how does jQuery(sizzle), and other libraries do it

jQuery uses the prototype.  It kind of hides that fact by aliasing the prototype to `.fn`, but it is still the prototype.  Here's [the jQuery function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L18).

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
},
```

And, here's [the aliasing](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L38):

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype
```

And, the implementation of [the actual jQuery constructor](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L18):

```
init = jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context, root ) {
    var match, elem;

    // HANDLE: $(""), $(null), $(undefined), $(false)
    if ( !selector ) {
        return this;
    }

    // Method init() accepts an alternate rootjQuery
    // so migrate can support jQuery.sub (gh-2101)
    root = root || rootjQuery;

   .....
```

And, the round-about [assignment of the `.init.prototype'](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L117):

```
// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```